# Build C# project process does not copy dependency assemblies to output folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

I am testing a code targeting **.NET standard 2.0**, in **Visual Studio 2022**. The code depends on `Polly` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly`. The program fails to start with error message :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Polly, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8a3ffc3f8f825cc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I found that the error occurred because the build project process does not copy the `Polly.dll` to folder `NetRetry\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0`. But why are these assemblies not copied to output folder? I can find these assemblies in `.nuget\packages` folder.

---

To reproduce this error

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Http;
using Polly;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var h = Policy
            .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            .Or<Exception>()
            .RetryAsync(3, (r, count) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Log retry {count}");
                    r.Result.Dispose();
                });

        var handler = new PolicyHttpMessageHandler(h);
        handler.InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

        HttpClient c = new HttpClient(handler);
        var result = c.GetAsync("https://www.google.com/non-existing", CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

NetRetry.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>True</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

---

I tried retargeting project to .NET 5.0 and build the project. This time the assemblies are all copied to folder `NetRetry\bin\Debug\net5.0`, and the program runs normally.

Comment: runnable applications should't target netstandard. It's designed for libraries

Answer (score 1):

Manually enable `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` will solve this.

Add to `PropertyGroup`

```
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Comment: This seems to have worked for an old Framework 4.6.1 NuGet package that we updated to 4.8 (no ROI to move to Net)